# npm install hangs on loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree: sill install loadIdealTree

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a Node.js application. When I try to run `npm install` it hangs with this:

```
loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree: sill install loadIdealTree
```

`npm install --verbose` gives me a little extra info:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--verbose',
npm verb cli   'aws-sdk-js' ]
npm info using npm@5.8.0
npm info using node@v8.9.2
npm verb npm-session ea38310110279de7
npm http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sdk-js 2211ms
npm verb stack Error: 404 Not Found: aws-sdk-js@latest
npm verb stack     at fetch.then.res (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/fetch.js:42:19)
npm verb stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
npm verb stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
npm verb stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
npm verb stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
npm verb stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
npm verb stack     at Async._drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
npm verb stack     at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
npm verb stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
npm verb stack     at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
npm verb stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
npm verb stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)
npm verb cwd /Users/me/git/aws-sdk-js-perf
npm verb Darwin 17.5.0
npm verb argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--verbose" "aws-sdk-js"
npm verb node v8.9.2
npm verb npm  v5.8.0
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: aws-sdk-js@latest
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2018-05-24T10_30_55_688Z-debug.log
```

I came across instances where other people experienced this but the below seemed to resolve their issue. It doesn't fix mine:

```
npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Does anybody know what might be wrong?

Comment: I have fix the issue: . I configure proxy for external access then it allow/bypass to install angular package. Check with your team to get .bat file and run it or set proxy manually.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Had the same issue, and this comment [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17228#issuecomment-318581491) fixed it for me:

> Try to remove 'package-lock.json' file from directory where 'package.json' locate.

Comment: Additionally I had to remove `node_modules` to make npm work again

Comment: There was no  'package-lock.json' file , tried all the things nothing worked but `npm config set strict-ssl false`

Comment: sigh... i do every all of this and still stucked ... deleting node_modules and package.json and runed `npm config set strict-ssl false` any other options?

Comment: I experienced this when I was on a vpn.  I stopped the vpn and it worked.

Comment: I experienced this when I wasnt on vpn... turns out some of the dependencies were local to my works servers only accessible via VPN

Comment: I removed yarn lock then it worked

Comment: In my case i had to do the other way around and restore package.lock file that I deleted earlier

Answer (score 34):

Simply follow the following given steps:

1. `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ --global`
2. `npm cache clear --force`
3. Delete your *package-lock.json* file(it will automatically get created after npm i).
4. Now try for `npm install`

This worked for me.

Comment: use https://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: verify your registry config after you do above change -  npm config get registry

Answer (score 25):

This problem happens also when you have a very slow connection

Comment: My stats are : ping=9ms  download=40 MBPS download=3.9M BPS. I can watch a anime on the same browser with any problem :s

Comment: I just had this problem a few minutes ago.

I can't be 100 percent sure, but I am pretty sure that switching to my phone's hotspot was the thing that fixed it.

Also, the rest of the family are all gaming / streaming,  so the network is under some strain ...

Comment: My connection had been slow all morning, didn't suspect that was that cause for this but it was, thanks!

Comment: Or no connection at all. Had this problem when buggy VM decided it didn't want to connect to the internet.

Comment: I just had this issue. A connectivity issue is the only explanation (after following instructions in the other top post). On a 00M fibre that was showing 95+ up / 60+ down to a local server (in south Asia right now). But guessing the route to the registry node it was connecting was slow. Switched to 4G and worked.

Comment: Yep. Switched to mobile hotspot and it worked.

Answer (score 14):

In my case, changing VPN worked.

Comment: In my case, disabling VPN worked.

Comment: Yes, enabling the VPN worked for me. I hadn't noticed mine had disconnected.

Answer (score 13):

I have tried all the solutions above without success.
But I found this one : https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4163#issuecomment-1010037450

```
alias npm="node --dns-result-order=ipv4first $(which npm)"
```

Then npm work correctly

Answer (score 12):

I also faced the same issue. In my case `git://` port was blocked and `npm install` took too long to time out. (longer than normal it waits before concluding that the process hung.)

A solution was to auto-rewrite all `git://` URLs to `https://`:

Run the following command in your terminal

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://

npm install
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I believe this is my issue too, but not the port. I've been having routing issues with my internet provider. That's most likely the case

Comment: I dont think `npm` has anything to do with `git` using this is not recommanded.

Comment: This caused npm to simply hang for me for a solid 90 seconds instead, then proceed with the same problem as before.

Answer (score 10):

Even after removing **package-lock.json**, `npm i` didn't worked for us. Instead, it got stuck on another message - `still removeObsoleteDep removing fs-extra from the tree as its been replaced by a newer version`.

Problem was, we used **yarn** occasionally. Installing using `yarn` will resolve the issue if it is the case.

Comment: For most people using NPM, adding yarn as well as NPM is a bad idea. It's worth choosing either yarn or NPM but installing both and using both in your project will come back to bite you when you use CI, and in development in general -some things yarn supports, but NPM doesn't, and vice-versa, and when you're running commands and they fail, it's a complete pain and makes you bleed development time. Least that's the very recent experience we had.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem and the issue was that my VPN connection dropped and some of the packages were in my companies private package store.

Answer (score 7):

This might happen when changing from node v16 to v18 or later.

Changing IPv6 settings resolves this issue.

**On MAC OS:**

system settings -> network -> your connected network (usually Wi-Fi) -> details -> TCPI/IP -> Configure IPv6 -> "**Link-Local only**"

Comment: I tried everything for about an hour until I found this answer.  How did you ever figure this out?

Comment: same here. for seo: got yarn internet connection issues first.

Answer (score 5):

This was my issue.  I forget that I had previously setup an internal proxy for work to get Node modules.    To check whether you are behind a proxy and see your proxy settings do:

```
npm config list
```

Mine output was:

`https-proxy = "http://9.116.33.175/max*emphasized text*"`

To clear it do:

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

Answer (score 3):

You might not have `package-lock.json` so instead of this file you need to remove the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file and try to execute `npm install` again.

About npm-shrinkwrap.json:

> npm-shrinkwrap.json is a file created by npm-shrinkwrap. It is
>   identical to package-lock.json , with one major caveat: Unlike
>   package-lock.json , npm-shrinkwrap.json may be included when
>   publishing a package.

Answer (score 3):

In my case package-lock.json file didn't exists. I tried with my mobile hotspot and it worked. Might be some issue from wifi end. But my internet was working fine on wifi. Just issue was it got stuck on

> loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree: sill install loadIdealTree

Moving on different network can also resolve your issue. I know it is very weird. Hope this will help too. To someone in future.

Comment: Moving on different network solved this issue

Comment: Glad It worked for you

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue went away as soon as I disconnect from my company's VPN.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30918112)

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**

Try reverting to node version `16.2.0`, then update your `npm` registry.

```
nvm install 16.2.0
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Try to install any node package e.g. `npm install --global yarn`

---

It is also helpful to clean your workspace by deleting your `node_modules` folder in the current directory, and remove `package-lock.json` file wherever `package.json` is located.

Other suggested some networking troubleshooting

- [MacOS M1:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73925444/12022522)

> System Preferences --> Network --> press Advanced --> TCP/IP tab --> on Configure IPv6 select `Link-local only` and apply

- [Ubuntu 22.04:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70865039/npm-install-hangs-on-sill-idealtree-build)

> disabling IPv6 fixed this for me.
>
> ```
> sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1 
> sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
> ```

---

**Background**

I was really struggling with this. I saw that reverting to node `v16.2.0` was a potential solution, but my `nvm` kept failing to download new node versions. I would see:

```
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.2.0/node-v16.2.0.tar.xz...
################################################                                                                                                       32.2%
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.2.0/node-v16.2.0.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /Users/<user>/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.2.0/node-v16.2.0.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
```

I solved this problem by clearing the cache of `nvm`. Then I was able to revert from node `v19.8.0` to `v16.2.0` then reset my `npm` registry.

- If you're not able to revert (`nvm` fails) try:

```
nvm cache clear
nvm install 16.2.0
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

- If you are getting SSL certificate errors, try using `http://` protocol instead with:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

*note:* You can check your `npm` registry with `npm config get registry`

Comment: Disabling IPv6 on Ubuntu 22.04 worked for me today. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this, and had removed my package-lock.json and found out that a resource wasn't available on the network I was on.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem.

When I tried yarn, I got this message:

> [1/4] Resolving packages... info There appears to be trouble with your
>   network connection. Retrying...

One of the packages was not available actually!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I check the config about registry again.

`npm get registry`

And check this IP is working.

---

cuz' I find that I was setting something else like http://10.1.1.1

--- the self-registry like Verdaccio who's proxy here, but it's shutdown.

and I set again `npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org`,

then it's work.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that helped me is commenting out the `proxy` & `https-proxy` lines at `.npmrc` file.

I don't even know how and when those two lines were set. Don't remember myself doing it.

Answer (score 2):

NetBSD 9.3 solution - hardcode the `registry.npmjs.org` IP due to IPV6 problems.

edit: [source](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4237#issuecomment-1212141446) - thanks khorben!

There's *something* weird going on with IPV6, what *exactly* I don't know, but a quick fix is to insert `registry.npmjs.org` into your `/etc/hosts`.

Get the IP:

```bash
ping registry.npmjs.org
```

Copy the IP (should be IPV4).

Open up `/etc/hosts`, with `su` powers, and insert the following line:

```
<PASTE THE IP HERE> registry.npmjs.org
```

So it turns into something like this on the last line:

```
104.16.26.35 registry.npmjs.org
```

Save the file.

Now `npm` should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced this issue too. Cause : proxy was not set.

Use these commands to set your proxy:
npm config set proxy http://username:password@host:port npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@host:port.
proxy=http://username:password@host:port https-proxy=http://username:password@host:port https_proxy=http://username:password@host:port

Post this, npm install went through with no issues

Answer (score 1):

This is my process:

1. `npm install --verbose` => Understand better what got hung. Got stuck at `loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree`
2. Removed `package-lock.json` from the same location as `package.json` => got stuck at `FetchMetadata`
3. Do `ssh-add`, add in my key like [this suggestion](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17228#issuecomment-333857122) => SUCCESS

Answer (score 1):

run:

```
npm cache clear --force
npm config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com
```

[Source : https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4876#issuecomment-1174884230](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4876#issuecomment-1174884230)

Answer (score 1):

In my case - I was using the wrong node version (not the `lts` one), so I just used the [node version manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), and installed the latest `lts` version:

```bash
nvm install --lts
```

Hope it helps ✌️

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve it in 2 ways

1. Delete 'package-lock.json'
2. Remove proxy settings (http_proxy / https_proxy) from environment variables

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. For me it was caused by a [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) watcher. Stopping the watcher instantly advances the process.

Answer (score 0):

if you still have trouble with this for windows users especially. U can start with re-install your npm in C:/yourfolder .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried removing the `package-lock.json` file but that did not work.

In the end updating node on my Mac to the latest version fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use my own npm repo for some modules, and when it was down, the `npm i` just hangs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had corrputed my npm config while trying a few other things.

i had added a cafile property

removed it using

```
npm config edit
```

Answer (score 0):

So for my case it was a bugy latest version of node with npm.

I rocomande you to always check if you are on a LTS (Long Time Support) version since this ones are daily maintained and stable version.

I was using node without nvm so my first step was to remove it (purge it) it's a simple topic and you can get lot of solution on google depending on your OS.

Then I had to install mvn, you can also use it tutorial of install who uses Curl: **in case you get a curl issue dont worry first open the curl install script on browser and copy past it on a folder in an install.sh file, dont forget to make it executable `sudo chmod +x myInstall.sh` then you can run it in your terminal**

Once nvm installed you may get an issue where nvm is enable to find the remote repository, dont worry all you have to do is to add a file containing this line :

```
sudo nano ~/.curlrc    # use this or vim to create the source file 

-k   # put this as content and save
```

Now your nvm should be fine

To install a stable version use the following commande to search repos for LTS versions

```
nvm ls-remote | grep LTS
```

Choose any version you want for my case for example

```
nvm install v16.13.0
```

Now you will see that node got installed with a corresponding version of npm (I dont recommande updating npm in this case to avoid latest version issues )

Go ahaid and do your `npm install xxxx@xxxx` this should work just fine

Dont forget to read your project requirement and choose corresponding node and npm version.

nvm can switch current version of node and npm, go ahaid and read it documentation using  `nvm --help`

Answer (score 0):

Just execute the following code in your node js cmd:

1. **git config --global http.sslVerify false**
2. **npm install**

This worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue and in my case, I did upgrade the node version which fixed the issue also sometimes we need to try with or without a VPN. Please downgrade the node version if require and if that is compatible with your packages.

Answer (score 0):

For me (MacOs 12.5 m1 machine) it was the ssh-agent issue. This [comment](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17228#issuecomment-333857122) fixed the issue for me.
Run `ssh-add` and enter passphrase if any to add the current ssh-key to the ssh-agent. You can verify this using `ssh-add -l`

You can add the ssh-agent permanently to the keychain. To the `.ssh/config` file, add the following lines:

```
 Host *
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm install` was hanging for me when Windows ransomware protection was blocking folder access to `node.exe`.

This can be checked in Windows Security:

Virus & threat protection > Ransomware protection > Allow an app through controlled folder access > Add an allowed app > Recently blocked apps

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution!

I realized ip6tables was dropping ICMPv6 packets on `npm ping`. I allowed ICMPv6 packets through and it solved it.

Well, not exactly...

- I saw dropped ICMPv6 packets.
- I went `ip6tables -P INPUT ACCEPT`. `npm ping` and `npm i` worked.
- I restored `ip6tables -P INPUT DROP` and added an ICMPv6 `ACCEPT` rule. npm still worked.
- I removed the ICMPv6 rule, just to be sure. npm **still** worked, although it didn't work earlier with the same conditions.

So I can't exactly explain what happened. Check if your firewall drops any packets on an npm command, and take it from there.

Comment: This partially worked for me, everime I boot the system I've to do:
`npm cache clear --force && 
npm config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com && sudo ip6tables -P INPUT ACCEPT`

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck there when i was setting up a private registry/Proxy with Verdaccio. So for devs in the future that made the same error as me:

Make sure you set the uplink in your Verdaccio-Config correctly:

```yaml
uplinks:
  npmjs:
    url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

And when you change your npm configs, make sure you set the protocol aswell! dont do `npm set registry localhost:4873`, do `npm set registry http://localhost:4873`.

And for good measurement (i followed the steps provided here first so i dont know if this actually helps), just clean the cache, delete the lockfile etc (follow Top answer).

Answer (score 0):

I turned off VPN running on my Chrome browser and it made it run. While no other solutions worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

**Can't give up more :(**

mine was

```
idealTree:npm: sill idealTree buildDeps
```

[Download yarn here manually](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases). If u r on windows download the .msi one, so ez

Answer (score -1):

If you have package-lock.json file in your folder. Try to delete it and then run npm install command again. This should helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

sometimes your internet speed  is slow that's why it take sometime to download the required files. just wi

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).