# Node Manager gets stuck during npm install at idealTree module

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

New mac user here. I'm trying to create a composer project in phpstorm (laravel/laravel) but every time I run `npm install` the process gets stuck at:

```
npm timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 0ms
⸨⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⸩ ⠸ idealTree:stuttard_staging: sill idealTree buildDeps
```

Full error report (after ~10 minutes freeze):

```
npm timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 1181143ms
npm timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree Completed in 1181150ms
npm timing command:i Completed in 1181156ms
npm verb type system
npm verb stack FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/axios failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1123:80
npm verb stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:110:14)
npm verb stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm verb stack     at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
npm verb stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:402:35)
npm verb stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
npm verb stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
npm verb stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm verb cwd /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/stuttard_staging
npm verb Darwin 20.6.0
npm verb argv "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/17.2.0/bin/node" "/opt/homebrew/bin/npm" "i" "--verbose"
npm verb node v17.2.0
npm verb npm  v8.1.4
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/axios failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1123:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm verb exit 1
npm timing npm Completed in 1181269ms
npm verb unfinished npm timer reify 1638537601466
npm verb unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1638537601470
npm verb code 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/artur/.npm/_logs/2021-12-03T13_39_42_628Z-debug.log
```

This issue seems to exist since years with node versions `14+`. I'm using `node 17.2` with `npm 8.1.4` and still seem to get it. Some threads tell to delete `package-lock.json` folder which I don't have.

I've tried configuring the registry:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

or clear the cache:

```
npm cache clear --force
```

but nothing seems to help. I've tried all of the solutions provided in these threads, without success:

[git 3359](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3359)

[git 17228](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17228)

[npm install hangs on idealTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50522376/npm-install-hangs-on-loadidealtreeloadalldepsintoidealtree-sill-install-loadid)

Could this be an issue with my network configuration? As I said, I'm mac noob. Any way to check?

**Edit:**

I was able to get it to work by downgrading to ancient software:

```
node 14.17.4
npm 6.14.14
```

This is just a temporary fix and I would love to know How to make it work with current software versions.

Comment: For some reason, I get errors such as this a lot using npm.  I use yarn, as I was never able to fully resolve the network errors I was receiving with npm. Perharps give yarn a try.

Comment: @silencedogood on windows `npm` worked fine but if this keeps happening on the mac I might give `yarn` a go.

Comment: @silencedogood Hey, just wanted to say that I'm using `yarn` now which works great and is faster than `npm`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a some problem after upgrade node into v16.

Remove all the config in `~/.npmrc` and `~/.node/etc/npmrc` file fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks!
I had same problem, in my .npmrc file I was using a registry that could be connected through VPN only.
So I removed configuration from this file and all worked fine.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was the internet connection (network security group).
Also if your ipv6 is the default and there is no ipv6 available may cause this.
So first check the internet connection either ping (if ICMP is allowed) or use curl for an address like https://registry.npmjs.org which is the repository of the npm.