# npm install stuck at sill install loadIdealTree

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

npm install  stuck at sill install loadIdealTree when I try to compile my application.

But I am able to run below commands on my system
npm install ionic
npm install cordova

I have cleared package-lock.json, node_modules on my applications.
Then ran but same error.
Updated from https to http proxy using npm config commands.
Then ran npm install , same error.

Since I am able to install ionic and cordova, not sure why npm install freezes at application level. Also same application , I am able to run npm install on other MacMachine

Any suggestion.

I am referring below post -
[npm install hangs on loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree: sill install loadIdealTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50522376/npm-install-hangs-on-loadidealtreeloadalldepsintoidealtree-sill-install-loadid)