# npm works only one time on one time connection to internet, requires frequent re-connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-scripts

Detailed Scenario
Connect to internet(wifi) on PC(pop-os)
Run an npm command - works fine
Run another npm command - stuck on (⠂⠂⠂) ⠧ idealTree:gdtot_data: sill idealTree buildDeps
Disconnect and reconnect to internet
Run an npm command - works fine
Run another npm command - stuck on (⠂⠂⠂) ⠧ idealTree:gdtot_data: sill idealTree buildDeps

What could be done to remove this thing.

It should run the commands back to back with no problem

Comment: what is `an npm command` ... what is `another npm command` ... are they the exact same npm command? what is the npm command? is it secret? did you want us to guess?

Comment: any npm command like npm install grammy and then again npm install axios

Comment: really? so any npm command works, and after that any npm command, doesn't matter which, always gets stuck on `idealTree:gdtot_data: sill idealTree buildDeps`

Comment: yeah, facing this problem today only, few days back worked fine. after many restarts, cache clear it doesn't help

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50522376/npm-install-hangs-on-loadidealtreeloadalldepsintoidealtree-sill-install-loadid) help

Comment: nope, doesn't work in new folders also, tried to change registry to https as well as http